# Browserstack custom reporter Cypress config

Tags: javascript, junit, mocha.js, cypress, browserstack

I'm using Cypress to run my e2e testing on Browserstack. I'm using `junit` reporter which is configured in the `cypress.json`. When I'm running tests locally test results are generated according to the format (i.e `junit`). However, when I'm running testing in Browserstack and fetch the results, they are not following the cypress config and are returned as mocha files.

Have anyone managed to make Browserstack return test results in `junit` format? Configs:

```
 cypress.json

{
  "reporter": "junit",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "mochaFile": "results/test-output-[hash].xml",
    "toConsole": true,
    "attachments": true
  }
}


  browserstack.json

{
    "auth": {...},
    "browsers": [...],

    "run_settings": {
      "cypress_config_file": "./cypress.json",
      "cypress_version": "6",
      "project_name": "FancyProjectName",
      "build_name": "Build no. 42",
      "parallels": "2",
      "npm_dependencies": {
        "typescript": "^4.2.4"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you need to add [mocha-junit-reporter](https://github.com/michaelleeallen/mocha-junit-reporter) to `npm_dependencies` in browserstack.json?

Comment: I didn't give it a go, since cypress have a support for junit reporter out of the box, based on:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters#Custom-reporter

Comment: That's why I suggested it - there's no sign of `mocha-junit-reporter` in the local install, yet they say it is included.

Comment: Good point, but it didn't work